# Objective-C - method for bool from webservice

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this web service:

```
<boolean xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">true</boolean>
```

And I have this method here:

```
-(void)deviceCheck:(NSString *)device Completetion:(void (^) (NSArray * result,NSError * error))completion{
    NSString *deviceRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?device=%@",webservice,device];
    NSURL *JSONURL = [NSURL URLWithString:deviceRequestString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:JSONURL];
    NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                                                      completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                                                                          if(data == nil){
                                                                              completion(nil,error);
                                                                              return;
                                                                          }
                                                                          NSError *myError;
                                                                          NSArray *tableArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&myError]];
                                                                          completion(tableArray,myError);
                                                                      }];
    [dataTask resume];
}
```

but when i call this:

```
[self deviceCheck:[[UIDevice currentDevice] name] Completetion:^(NSArray *result, NSError *error) {

            if(result == nil){

                UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Device is not valid." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

                UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
                [alertController addAction:ok];

                [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

            }else{

            }
}];
```

The result is nil.

What am I doing wrong here? How would I call this web service that is a boolean.

I did an NSLog on error:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1022 "The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection.
```

Fixed that error with this: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4560

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set."
```

Comment: Do some debugging. In the `dataTaskWithRequest` completion method, is `data` `nil`? If so, what is the error?

Comment: data is nil and now I am having issues with breakpoints and it appears my method is not being called

Comment: This is the error I get NSError NSError domain: @"NSURLErrorDomain" - code: 4294966294

Comment: Update your question with the full output of `NSLog(@"Error: %@, error);`.

Comment: I have updated my question with full output

Comment: OK, now search on that error. It has been discussed and answered many times.

Comment: Updated question....new error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `NSJSONSerialization` to parse the response of your web service. But your web service is returning `XML` and not `JSON`.

So what you want to do is either see if your web service can return `JSON` responses or change your code to parse that `XML` response.

You can use the built-in `NSXMLParser` class to parse the `XML` response. But it is low level and will require a good amount of code.

Comment: See my modified answer. Check out the documentation for `NSXMLParser` and post some code here if you have followup questions.

Answer (score 0):

> The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection.

Since iOS9, Apple requires you to talk HTTP to properly configured SSL endpoints. If your web service is not using a proper SSL endpoint then you need to fix that.

If you cannot fix your web service to use a good SSL configuration then you must think hard about wether this is a good idea. If your service is accessible over plain HTTP without SSL then it is trivial for attackers in many scenarios to listen in and even modify calls to your web service.

If you would like to make an exception to the *App Transport Security* requirements then you can do so in your application's `Info.plist` file. This is well documented in the [App Transport Security Technote](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016240)

**Personal opinion: Disabling ATS completely, by setting `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to `YES`, is not a solution. It is usually a lazy workaround that possibly puts your users at risk. Specially in 2015 where unwarranted surveillance, identity theft and data breaches happen more often than you wish for.**